# Drupal 8 Delete layout prefix

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a page, created via page manager with the layout type - "One Column". I placed blocks on the page and when I open this page, I see my blocks wrapped by a

```
<div class="block-region-content">
```

When I print `content` variable in twig template, I can see that this `div` is the value of `#prefix` property

```
content array(12)
   'content' => array(4)
      '#prefix' => string(34) "<div class="block-region-content">"
      '#suffix' => string(6) "</div>"
```

How can I delete this properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to achieve this. For example, you should probably preprocess blocks within your theme (same can be done from a module though)  :

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  // Act on a specific block, eg. here the page title block 
  if ($vars['plugin_id'] === 'page_title_block') {
    unset ($vars['content']['#prefix'], $vars['content']['#suffix']);
  }  
}
```